# Wordpress enable php filedownload for users

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, nginx, file-type

I cannot provide a php file for download within my article.

I installed https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-extra-file-types/# and disabled all uplaod checks. I Uplaoded my php. I enabled all checks again. The URl from the Media Library, does still not download, but executes/opens.

Comment: The plugin you are using there, only modifies what file types WP will _allow_ you to upload to its media library. It doesn't change anything about how the web server will _handle_ these files, when you request them directly via HTTP. You would either need to get your system configured to _not_ send `.php` files in that folder (and subfolders) through the PHP parser; or you need to rewrite those requests _to_ a PHP script, that will then read the file content and pass it on to the client.

Comment: Both could be _dangerous_, if you let users upload arbitrary files, or upload files yourself, that contain code you do not want to be _executed_ on your system - for example if the configuration what gets send through the PHP parser at some point changes without your knowledge, or if your rewrite to a PHP script got disabled. It would probably make much more sense, if you simply uploaded this as a `.txt` file, and told the user they have to _rename_ it before they will be able to use it on their system.

Comment: text files are also not supported: https://wordpress.com/forums/topic/why-cant-i-upload-and-link-to-plain-text-files-txt-files/#:~:text=Unfortunately%2C%20we%20don%E2%80%99t%20allow%20.txt%20files%20for%20security%20reasons%2C%20as%20they%20could%20contain%20executable%20scripts.%20What%20are%20you%20trying%20to%20do%20specifically%20with%20the%20file%3F

Comment: But that's something the plugin you mentioned can work around, no?

Answer (score 0):

My Solution to this was finally, placing the .php file inside of a zip File, which is upload-/ and downloadable by default.